# Register constructors in a factory automatically

Tags: c#, factory

I have a base class DataSet and several derived classes (DataSetSeries, DataSetTable, ...). The constructors of the derived classes each take exactly one argument the type of which is specific to the derived class, e.g.

```
public DataSetSeries(Series s);
public DataSetTable(Table t);
```

I have written a (generic) factory class that allows me to create instances of DataSet subclasses from the corresponding original data types, e.g.

```
DataSet aDataSetSeries = DataSet.Factory.Create(aSeries);    
DataSet aDataSetTable = DataSet.Factory.Create(aTable);
```

where DataSet.Factory is a static readonly field of DataSet. What Create does is determine the type of its argument, then try to lookup the corresponding constructor delegate (which has been registered before) from a dictionary and execute the delegate if it exists.

So I have to register each of the derived classes' constructors at the factory. In order to keep similar things close together and not to forget to add the registration for any new DataSet subclass, I wanted to do this registration in the derived DataSet-classes instead of DataSet itself (which isn't supposed to know any of its derived classes in a strict OO sense). Because Factory is static, I am trying to include a static constructor in each derived DataSet, e.g.

```
public class DataSetSeries: DataSet
{
    static DataSetSeries()
    {
        Factory.Register(typeof(Series), data => new DataSetSeries((Series)data));
    }
    // ...
}
```

But now here is my problem: **the static constructor of DataSetSeries will only be called upon first usage of DataSetSeries**. But the first thing I will do is call DataSet.Factory.Create(aSeries), which is not a method of DataSetSeries and so there is no first usage of DataSetSeries at all. **Hence the static constructor will never be called**.

How could I get this working without explicitely iterating over all derived types (which was the reason for setting up the factory in the first place)?

Comment: Have you considered using a dependency container, such as [Autofac](https://autofac.org/)? Normally I wouldn't recommend using a dependency container, but in your case it might make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a static constructor for factory and inside this constructor can find all sub-classes of Dataset (DataSetSeries, DataSetTable, ...). and call static constructor for them.

```
public static class Factory
{
    static Factory()
    {
        var datasetDerrivedTypes = Assembly
            .GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t => typeof(DataSet).IsAssignableFrom(t) &&
                        t != typeof(DataSet));

        foreach (var type in datasetDerrivedTypes)
        {
            System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(type.TypeHandle);  
        }
    }

    public static void Register(Type type, Func<Series, DataSet> constructorDelegate)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Works... almost. Because Register(...) is an instance method in my case (so I might have several different factories), it assumes that the Factory instance already exists. But Factory's static constructor is called before its first instance is created, so the myFactory that is accessed through myFactory.Register(...) is null at 'static time'. But I could just solve it by moving your proposed static constructor to DataSet itself (which owns myFactory).